# How to differ BB browser and Webworks Application

Tags: javascript, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I have a Webworks application (actually, it's just a single-page application) and I'd like to run it as an application (bar-file) and as a web-site.

So is there any way to differ Webworks application from browser? I've tried to use `navigator.userAgent` but it's identical in both environments, smth like:

"*Mozilla/5.0 (BB10; Touch) AppleWebKit/537.10+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.9.2743 Mobile Safari/537.10+*"

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to do this, likely the easiest is to check `window.webworks` or `window.blackberry` as both should exist by default in a webworks application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'd like to determine it before webworks loaded. The goal is to determine should the application wait for webworks (bar-file application) or it should start initialization on `document.ready` (browser version).